# What purpose is served by having an async keyword for a callback inside an awaited function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
async createApiCall(apiCalls: IApiCallsTable):Promise<IApiCallsTable> {
  try {
    const instance: any = this.db.getEntities().dbo__api_calls.build(apiCalls);
    instance.isNewRecord = true;
    let result = await this.db.getSequelize().transaction( async (transaction) => {
      return instance.save();
    });
    return Promise.resolve(result.dataValues);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    let message: ILogMessage = {
      code: ResponseErrorCode.unknownError,
      message: ResponseErrorCode.unknownError.toString(),
      meta: error,
      sourceFunction : 'ApiCallsQueries: createApiCall()'
    };
    log.error(message);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

I would to understand if is it necessary to have an `async` labelling an anonymous function, i.e. `this.db.getSequelize().transaction( async (transaction) => { ...`? The code is working flawlessly, but I cannot seem to understand the reason to label a callback `async` if nothing is being awaited inside it? Is this a recommended pattern and/or best practice?

PS: Any further suggestions/recommendations on how this code could be improved are more than welcome :)

Comment: you have this line `let result = await` (line number 5). I guess the question can be closed then?

Comment: @smnbbrv - OP is probably referring to `async (transaction) => {
      return instance.save();
    }` - but that's just guessing from reading the code and the question

Comment: you are probably right. What is then the point to post all this surrounding things...

Comment: You should not use *any* (asynchronous) callbacks in a function that has `await`

Comment: @smnbbrv The point was to avoid further questions regarding the code. So full clarity it is, I guess.

Comment: Why mustn't I? @Bergi

Comment: @fshock In general you should not combine promise style with nodebacks. In this case, `transaction` appears to be an exception (similar to Bluebirds `use`) that requires the syntactic nesting for semantic purposes, and does deal with promises itself just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Sequelize.transaction()`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L6055) expects a callback function that returns a `Promise`. `async` transforms any function into a `Promise`-returning function.
 However, [`Model.save()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-save) already returns a `Promise`, so you should be able to use just:

```
await this.db.getSequelize().transaction((tx) => instance.save());
```

---

`async` instructs the runtime to translate a function into continuation-passing style; that is, turn it into function that returns a `Promise` that eventually resolves with the function's return value. This is independent of whether or not you use `await` in the body of the function.

The TypeScript definition for [`Sequelize.transaction()`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L6055) has this as the signature of the method you're using:

```
transaction(autoCallback: (t: Transaction) => PromiseLike<any>): Promise<any>;
```

In TypeScript, it's invalid to pass a "regular" function to a callback parameter that expects a promise-returning function:

```
let foo: (() => PromiseLike<string>);

foo = async () => "aaa";            // this compiles
foo = () => Promise.resolve("aaa"); // this does as well
foo = () => "aaa";                  // this does *not*
```

(You can see it in the TS playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20foo%3A%20(()%20%3D%3E%20PromiseLike%3Cstring%3E)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20async%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22aaa%22%3B%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve(%22aaa%22)%3B%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22aaa%22%3B%0D%0A).) After all, a `Promise<string>` is very different from a `string`!

Your code however uses `async` on a method that already returns a `Promise<Model>`, meaning that your callback actually returns a `Promise<Promise<Model>>`. This doesn't seem right, and your code should actually cause TypeScript to complain about `result.dataValues`, since `result` will be of type `Promise<Model>`, not `Model`. I'm guessing it came about by starting with code with the following basic shape:

```
transaction(async (tx) => {
    let foo = await Foo.find();
    // use foo
    return await foo.save();
});
```

where they keywords are used appropriately, since it doesn't just pass through a promise.

Comment: Of course a regular (non-`async`) function that explicitly returns a promise is valid as well

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I updated the examples given to include it

Comment: It actually made me investigate the OP and the Sequelize docs more closely and rework the answer to hopefully be closer to what happened here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using the `await` keyword inside a function body, you don't need to label any function as `async`.

An exception to this rule, is if you want that callback to behave like a `Promise`, which you don't in your code example.

```
let result = await this.db.getSequelize().transaction( async (transaction) => {
  return instance.save();
});
```

Even if `instance.save` returns a `Promise`, which I'm guessing it does - you're already covered here without using `async` at all, since you're already building a proper `Promise` chain.